# could not get any response

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, api

I am building a rest api with node.js and mysql. But in my GET I am getting a error of "could not get any response" with router.get that uses the mysql.
Here is my code, mt it helps.

server.js

```
const http =  require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/user');
var mysql = require("mysql");
//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : ' ',
        database : 'achai_db'
    });
    res.locals.connection.connect();
    next();
});
```

user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * from users', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

In that user.js if i use a get without using the mysql the connection works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand JavaScript nature(Asynchronous programming) and you must not open `mysql` connection in each request, you can use connection pooling and keep connection open, just acquire connection and release it after query.

updated `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/user');
const mysql = require('mysql');
//Database connection
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : ' ',
    database : 'achai_db'
});
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        res.locals.connection = connection;
        next(err);
    });      
});
```

updated `user.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * from users', function (error, results, fields) {
        res.locals.connection.release();
        if (error) throw error;
        //res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```